# Linear transformation different notation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Linear transformation $A: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ which is given by

$$A\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2x-z\\ 
-x+y-3z\\
-x-2z
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone explain to me what this kind of notation of a linear transformation actually means? In the exercise, we need to find the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. But the thing is I don't even understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking for you to find the matrix $A$ such that $A\pmatrix{x \\y \\z}=\pmatrix{2x-z \\ -x +y -3z \\ -x-2z}$,

where $\pmatrix{x \\y \\z}$ is an arbitrary vector in $R^3$.

To find $A$, you can use the fact that the columns of A will be the vectors to which the standard basis vectors will be mapped to under the transformation.

That is,

$A\pmatrix{1 \\0 \\0} = \pmatrix{2 \\-1 \\-1}$,

$A\pmatrix{0 \\1 \\0} = \pmatrix{0 \\1 \\0}$,

$A\pmatrix{0 \\0 \\1} = \pmatrix{-1 \\-3 \\-2}$.

So $A=\pmatrix{2 &0 &-1 \\ -1& 1& -3 \\ -1& 0& -2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Would it have helped if the question had been written as below?

$A\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 2 &  0& -1\\ 
-1& 1& -3\\
-1& 0& -2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: So this is the matrix $A$ if I am not mistaking?

Comment: Yes, that's right.